# ThreadContext is null when using AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I have the following code:

```
@Bean(name = "SomeDataSource")
    public DataSource custAcctDboDataSource() throws SQLException {

        Map<Object, Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
        dataSources.put(ClientDatabase.DB_US_EAST_1, dataSourceUsEast1()); // DB from USEAST1
        dataSources.put(ClientDatabase.DB_US_EAST_2, dataSourceUsEast2()); // DB from USEAST1

        AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new MultitenantDataSource();

        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourceUsEast1());
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
        dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();

        return dataSource;
    }
```

---

```
public enum ClientDatabase {

    DB_US_EAST_1, DB_US_EAST_2
}
```

---

```
public class TenantContext {

    private static final ThreadLocal<ClientDatabase> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(ClientDatabase clientDatabase) {
        Assert.notNull(clientDatabase, "clientDatabase cannot be null");
        CONTEXT.set(clientDatabase);
    }

    public static ClientDatabase getClientDatabase() {
        return CONTEXT.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        CONTEXT.remove();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MultitenantDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

        System.out.println(ThreadContext.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("The current tenant value is ::--> " + 
TenantContext.getClientDatabase());
        return TenantContext.getClientDatabase();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class DaoService {

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository someRepository;

    public void loadTables(String tenant, String input){

        if (tenant.equalsIgnoreCase("US-EAST-1"))
            TenantContext.set(ClientDatabase.DB_US_EAST_1);
        else
            TenantContext.set(ClientDatabase.DB_US_EAST_2);

        System.out.println("Current Tenant -->" + TenantContext.getClientDatabase());
        Output output = someRepository.getSomeValue(input);

       if (customer != null){
            System.out.println(output.getSomeId() + "," + output.getSecondId());
       }else {
           System.out.println("No hit");
       }

        System.out.println("Second Call");
        output = someRepository.getSomeValue(input);

        if (customer != null){
            System.out.println(output.getSomeId() + "," + output.getSecondId());
        }else {
            System.out.println("No hit");
        }

        TenantContext.clear();
    }
}
```

---

In the above code for the class DaoService, I am trying to make first call to us-east-1 DB and for the second call I want the data should be fetched from us-east-2 DB. TenantContext.set function is of no value as it is not able to change anything. But I just get result from us-east-1 all the time. In my class MultitenantDataSource in the method determineCurrentLookupKey, TenantContext which is of type ThreadLocal is showing as empty and because of which always default database is chosen. What do I need to change in order for it to have some value rather than being null?

Comment: Disable open session in view, which leads to eager acquisition of a db connection. Or find another way of setting the tenant context in, for isntance, a srevlet filter which executes first, so that it is set for the whole request.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, I dont have a REST API call so using servlet filter wont help. This is going to be a kafka consumer.

Comment: Something you might want to add. Nonetheless you need to set the context before any transactional method being called. If your listener is transactional you are already too late to set it in that service method.

Comment: @M.Deinum, so I dont have the transactional method upfront. After making the changes as per your suggestions, this seems to be working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting @M.Deinum's comment as the answer.